# WMI printer.put() access denied

Tags: c#, printing

I am trying to modify the "Keep Printed Jobs" property for each printer using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsolePrintpref
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Modify printer parameters");

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
        scope.Connect();

        string searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer";
        ManagementObjectSearcher searchPrinters = new ManagementObjectSearcher(searchQuery);
        ManagementObjectCollection printerCollection = searchPrinters.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject printer in printerCollection)
        {
            PropertyDataCollection printerProperties = printer.Properties;
            foreach (PropertyData property in printerProperties)
            {
                if (property.Name == "KeepPrintedJobs")
                {
                    printerProperties[property.Name].Value = true;
                }
            }
            printer.Put(); //access denied
        }
     }
   }
}
```

But it throws the error:
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.ManagementException' occurred in System.Management.dll Additional information: Access denied

I am on the administrator account, and in WMImgmt it shows that the administrator has write permissions. Is there something I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: Did you run visual studio as admin?

Comment: Wow I guess that should have been obvious. Thanks.

Comment: NP. I will add it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run Visual Studio as administrator.